Install plugins in neovim
I’m new in nvim. I want to install typescript-language-service on nvim but can I not do that.
Please see all my configs and say me what should I do
The structure of my nvim 
my configs/lspconfig.lua file
-- EXAMPLE 
local configs = require("configs.lspconfig")

local on_attach = configs.on_attach
local on_init = configs.on_init
local capabilities = configs.capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = { "html", "cssls", "clangd"}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_init = on_init,
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

  --- typescript
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}

-- Without the loop, you would have to manually set up each LSP 
-- 
-- lspconfig.html.setup {
--   on_attach = on_attach,
--   capabilities = capabilities,
-- }
--
-- lspconfig.cssls.setup {
--   on_attach = on_attach,
--   capabilities = capabilities,
-- }

my custom/chadrc.lua file:
-- This file  needs to have same structure as nvconfig.lua 
-- https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/blob/v2.5/lua/nvconfig.lua

---@type ChadrcConfig
local M = {}

M.ui = {
    theme = "onedark",

    -- hl_override = {
    --  Comment = { italic = true },
    --  ["@comment"] = { italic = true },
    -- },
}
M.plugins = "custom.plugins"

return M

my custom/plugins.lua file:
local plugins = {
   {
   "williamboman/mason.nvim",
   opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "lua-language-server",
        "typescript-language-server",
        "html-lsp",
        "prettier",
        "stylua"
      },
    },
  },
-- In order to modify the `lspconfig` configuration:
{
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
   config = function()
      require("configs.lspconfig").defaults()
      require "configs.lspconfig"
   end,
},

}

return plugins

My Error Text with :MasonInstallAll command:
  typescript-language-server
  ▼ Displaying full log
    Initialized npm root.
    Installing npm package typescript-language-server@4.3.3…
    spawn: npm failed with exit code 1 and signal 0.

enter image description here
I installed and removed manytime nvchad.
But can I not do that.
my nvim version is 10
My nvchad version is 2.5

Do you have node installed?
